# I have problem with Pyinstaller in python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have a question if I use Pyinstaller to convert python file to exe will convert the modules with or not? , because i have python file with a lot of modules and i want to convert it how i can do it and avoiding this issue,
Thank u.

```
    import requests
```

error:

```
    ImportError: No module named requests
```

.

Comment: For the error `ImportError: No module named requests` tell us are you getting this error before building with pyinstaller or after ?

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui after when i use the file in another computer i didn't install the module in

Comment: Ok are you using virtualenv, or you install modules directly to your system? i highly encourage you to use a separate virtual environment  for each project .

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui install it directly,
idk how to use a virtual environment .new in python language

Comment: i thought so, anyway i highly encourage you to learn and use something like virtualenv. so you separate environments for each project of yours.

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui i will try it thank you

Comment: just one last question ..how you are building ? is it just  `pyinstaller your-script.py` ?

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui Sorry put after using virtual environment and install everything how i can convert all the files to exe file ?,
and im building licek ```pyinstaller --onefile my-script.py```

Comment: you mean just one stand alone exe file ?

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui yes

Comment: ok i will write an answer and try to explain

Comment: if the answer was correct please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in comments basically the error is occurring when you try to open the generated file in another computer, however your aren't using any virtual environment so you can install the requirements and try to rebuild again but rather you want a stanalone exe file.

For that use :

```
   pyinstaller --onefile your-script.py 


   # or pyinstaller -F your-script.py 
   
   ## this should generate a stand alone executable file located in the dist folder.
```

---

### **About your concerns on how pyinstaller works**

**Does pyinstaller make copies of modules when building ?**

The answer is simply : **yes** , as mentioned in the docs [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html) PyInstaller reads a Python script written by you. It analyzes your code to discover every other module and library your script needs in order to execute. Then it collects copies of all those files – including the active Python interpreter! – and puts them with your script in a single folder, or optionally in a single executable file.

**However**, the variations of Python and third-party libraries are endless and unpredictable, if something goes wrong you can learn how to fix those issues by reading this page on the docs [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html)

**What to generate ?**

you can read more [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyinstaller.html?highlight=--onefile#what-to-generate)

1. Create a one-folder bundle containing an executable (default), `-D, --onedir`
2. Create a one-file bundled executable. you need to use `-F ore --onefile`

**Finally**

I highly encourage you to use separate virtual environment for each project.

Comment: i tryed to make exe file from my py like u told me but when i try to open it i get this error and i couldn't fix it
```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
[1252] Failed to execute script pw
```

Comment: Ok does the script work when executing `python your-script.py` before using pyinstaller ? also Please update your question and post the content of your script.py so we have a better understanding of the code

Comment: Also did you used a virtual environment ? are you using your own modules etc ? a look at the code and the complete error log would be very helpful to understand where this error is comming from .

Comment: i can't post the cod its over 3000 chr,
and yes its work when i use python command

Comment: Ok if you have a github repo of the code i'm willing to help you later, but for me it seems to be something related to the modules you used because you installed them directly to the system  so something went wrong when copying the modules and libs maybe even some data etc, for that can you make a virtual environment for this code and install the required libs in that env and then try to build again.  and see if the error is fixed